# Python: exit the loop when an error is encountered

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I have a loop where I do some matrix operations per iteration. Howevever, at some point I begin getting singular matrices, the program just stops and does not continue the rest of the operations outside of the loop.

How can I just exit the loop whenever I encounter an error and continue with the rest of my program?

Comment: can you post some of the code you have tried? I recommend checking out https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve :)

Answer (score 0):

We have not enough information about your code or project. But you could try something with "try:"

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

So you're going to want to put your loop into a try except statement, put your loop below try :)

Here's the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

```
try:
   YourLoopCode
except RunTimeError:
   TheCodeHasGoneWrong
```

Comment: I have "LinAlgError: Matrix is singular", but when I do "except LinAlgError", I get "NameError: name 'LinAlgError' is not defined", and my programs stops completely again.

Comment: try changing to 'except LinAlgError:' maybe?

Comment: I did write "except LinAlgError:"

Comment: That's the original thing I tried, but it gives me "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  muX = nuX / np.sum(nuX)"

Comment: Please could you post some of your code, it's getting harder to help with this issue with no code to review :)